# Spring JPA/Hibernate in standalone app

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am utilizing spring in non web application and I am using hibernate for working with DB. Problem I am experiencing is that while "registerShutdownHook();" does close spring context container it does not properly shut down and close resources for JPA so my connections to DB are getting maxed out.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="pu" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
            <property name="showSql" value="false" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
```

I use configuration presented above to fire up JPA layer and use "@Transactional" annotations to inject EM's into DAO's.

Maybe someone could help me out what am I missing or how should I handle proper closing of JPA sessions in standalone environment ?

Thank you,

P.S. Exception I am getting is: java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect

Comment: I think @Transactional is NOT for injecting EMs, is it?

Comment: PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - scans for @Transactional annotation for injecting EM as far as I understand.

Comment: I believe it scan for `@PersistenceUnit` and `@PersistenceContext` instead

Comment: I apologize, I mistook `@Transactional` for `@PersistenceContext`. So what I actually meant that I used `@PersistenceContext` for injecting EM: e.g.:
    `@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
 private EntityManager entityManager;`

Comment: `<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="url" value="${DBUrl}" />
  <property name="username" value="${DBUsername}" />
  <property name="password" value="${DBPassword}" />
 </bean>
`
I use "-D" params for passing information. Problem is that I get java.net.SocketException at random. Some times I don't get that exception at all.

Answer (score 0):

1.Create transaction manager as follow :

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" >  
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistanceUnit"/>  
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>  
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:persistence.xml"/> 
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">  
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="${db.orm.showsql}" />              
            <property name="generateDdl" value="${db.orm.generateDdl}" />               
            <property name="database" value="${db.type}"/>  
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="${db.orm.dialect}" />
        </bean>
    </property>  
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

2.use persistance.xml(should be in classpath)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="persistanceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <description>Oracle db Persistence Unit</description>   
    <class>com.company.YourModelClass</class>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

3.Add following annotation in applicationContext.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.yourcompany.basepackage" />
```

4.annoatate your Entitymanager in service class like:

```
 @PersistenceContext
 private EntityManager em = null;
```

5.Inject TrasnsactionManager to :

```
private PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager = null;
```

6.persist object like:

```
platformTransactionManager .persist(obj);
```

Comment: I have removed the link to your blog. It is *not* an answer to this question. Do not post a link to it again like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is another example of application Context.xml with JPA.  It works fine for me.

```
       <context:property-placeholder location=”classpath:jdbc.properties”/>

      <!– Connection Pool –>

      <bean id=”dataSource” destroy-method=”close”>

        <property name=”driverClass” value=”${jdbc.driverClass}”/>

        <property name=”jdbcUrl” value=”${jdbc.url}”/>

        <property name=”user” value=”${jdbc.username}”/>

        <property name=”password” value=”${jdbc.password}”/>

    </bean>



      <!– JPA EntityManagerFactory –>

      <bean id=”entityManagerFactory”

                  p:dataSource-ref=”dataSource”>

            <property name=”jpaVendorAdapter”>

                  <bean>

                          <property name=”database” value=”${jdbc.database}”/>

                              <property name=”showSql” value=”${jdbc.showSql}”/>                       

            </bean>          

            </property>

      </bean>

      <!– Transaction manager for a single JPA EntityManagerFactory (alternative to JTA) –>
      <bean id=”transactionManager”

                  p:entityManagerFactory-ref=”entityManagerFactory”/>



      <!– Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes for eg @Autowired–>

      <context:annotation-config/>



        <!– enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations  –>

        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager=”transactionManager”/>



      <!– Property Configurator –>

    <bean id=”propertyConfigurer”>

            <property name=”location” value=”jdbc.properties”/>

      </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package=”com.test.dao”/>

</beans>
```